# What Maven plugin can copy a file into multiple JARs?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

i have a set of JARs. It can be any number of them. Is there a plugin i can use (like truezip-maven-plugin or maven-resources-plugin) that can copy a file into every JAR? From what i've seen truezip gets closest to this but i have to specify the JAR explicitly.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-my-file</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>process-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <from>${somefolder}/myfile.txt</from>
        <to>${project.build.directory}/*.jar/folderInsideJar/myfile.txt</to>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is the wildcard *.jar correct? Will it work like this? If not, what is the recommended way of doing it for multiple JARs?

UPDATE: i made my own plugin which does this

Thanks,
Teo

Comment: You have one project with multiply jars or project with subprojects and every subproject have one jar?

Comment: I have multiple projects, each with one jar

Comment: Then you should just configure any plugin that work with resources (not jars) on parent pom, for example standard resources plugin can use additional folder as source, or, much easier to use build-helper-plugin

Comment: Yes, that would be the simpler way out, but unfortunately i don't want this to happen the first time the jars are built, i want it at a later stage. Anyway, i found that making a Maven plugin is not hard at all, and i did just that :)

Comment: @Teo Care to share your answer?

Comment: @pjanssen just did it...

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of posting my own solution: i created a simple Maven plugin: https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;

public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * @parameter The directory which contains JARs to be signed
     */
    private String directory;

    /**
     * @parameter The name of the template to sign into the JARs
     */
    private String template;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        final File dir = new File(directory);
        final String[] jars = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".jar");
            }
        });
        final File jnlpTemplate = new File(template);
        byte[] templateBytes = null;
        try {
            templateBytes = toByteArray(jnlpTemplate);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String jar : jars) {
            try {
                File currentJar = new File(dir, jar);
                File newJar = new File(dir, "temp.jar");
                ZipFile old = new ZipFile(currentJar);
                ZipOutputStream append = new ZipOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(newJar));

                // first, copy contents from existing jar to new one
                Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = old.entries();
                while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    ZipEntry e = entries.nextElement();
                    append.putNextEntry(e);
                    if (!e.isDirectory()) {
                        copy(old.getInputStream(e), append);
                    }
                    append.closeEntry();
                }

                // now append some extra content
                ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry("JNLP-INF/" + jnlpTemplate.getName());
                append.putNextEntry(e);
                append.write(templateBytes);
                append.closeEntry();

                // close
                old.close();
                append.close();
                currentJar.delete();
                newJar.renameTo(new File(dir,jar));
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Could not sign " + jar + ": "
                        + t.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    // 4MB buffer
    private static final byte[] BUFFER = new byte[4096 * 1024];

    /**
     * copy input to output stream - available in several StreamUtils or Streams
     * classes
     */
    public static void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
            throws IOException {
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(BUFFER)) != -1) {
            output.write(BUFFER, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] toByteArray(File f) throws IOException {
        if (f.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(f + " is too large!");
        }
        int length = (int) f.length();
        byte[] content = new byte[length];
        int off = 0;
        int read = 0;
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
        try {
            while (read != -1 && off < length) {
                read = in.read(content, off, (length - off));
                off += read;
            }
            if (off != length) {
                // file size has shrunken since check, handle appropriately
            } else if (in.read() != -1) {
                // file size has grown since check, handle appropriately
            }
            return content;
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It was a long time ago :) But the basic idea is: you can pass 2 parameters to the Mojo, a directory full of JARs and the path to a file that should be put into each of those JARs.